# installing cPickle with python 3.5

Tags: python, docker, pickle, python-3.5

This might be silly but I am unable to install `cPickle` with python 3.5 docker image

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.5-onbuild
```

**requirements.txt**

```
cpickle
```

When I try to build the image

```
$ docker build -t sample .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.072 kB
Step 1 : FROM python:3.5-onbuild
# Executing 3 build triggers...
Step 1 : COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
Step 1 : RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 016c35a032ee
Collecting cpickle (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cpickle (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cpickle (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 171, accepted):

`cPickle` comes with the standard library… in python 2.x.  You are on python 3.x, so if you want `cPickle`, you can do this:

```
>>> import _pickle as cPickle
```

However, in 3.x, it's easier just to use `pickle`.

No need to install anything.  If something requires `cPickle` in python 3.x, then that's probably a bug.

Comment: ahh! is `_pickle` replacement for `cPickle` in python 3.x? or `pickle` would be as fast?

Comment: Yes, and `pickle` uses `_pickle`, so it's also fast and can handle subclasses.

Comment: I am using Python 3.6.6, and tried everything: import pickle as cPickle, import pickle, import _pickle as cPickle but still having the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cPickle' "

Comment: @pari: I do not believe that specific error can be generated from the three import statements you have detailed in your comment above.  Maybe you should investigate a bit further, and potentially ask a new SO question if it's indeed some new issue or some bug that you are experiencing.

Comment: In Python 2, cPickle is the accelerated version of pickle, and a later addition to the standard library. It was perfectly normal to import it with a fallback to pickle. In Python 3 the accelerated version has been integrated and there is simply no reason to use anything other than `import pickle`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this for both python 2 and 3

```
try:
  import cPickle as pickle
except:
  import pickle
```

Answer (score -1):

I am using python 3.10.9 and trying to run script written in python 2 , So after reading above comments,this commands works .
`import pickle as pkl`